# How to adjust row height of DBGrid - Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a DBGrid that receives data from an ADOTable in a data module for my project, but I noticed the text or fields of the records do not display fully. The bottom part of a "g" would be cut off due to the small row height. How do I code to change this?

I know you can change column widths. Could one do something similar for rows as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can do this at design-time is to define your own TDBGrid descendant, add a RowHeight property to it and install it in the IDE.

The following will work at run-time:

```
type
 TMyDBGrid = class(TDBGrid);

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).DefaultRowHeight := 32;
end;
```

This works because `DefaultRowHeight` is a protected property of `TCustomGrid`, from which TDBGrid descends.

Comment: Did this answer your q?

Comment: Yes, though this is a bit too complicated for my pathetic level of understanding XD
High school is useless.

Comment: Well, it would be good if you could accept the answer, because it is correct, as a 2-minute test would confirm.